# Finding index in list where the number begins to ascend

Tags: c#, linq

say i have a list of numbers, i want to know where in the list do the numbers begin decreasing, in no particular order, an example would be ideal!

```
1,
2,
2,
3,
3,
4,
4,
5,
5,
4, <= this should be my output
4,
3,
3,
2,
2,
1,
```

thanks

Comment: Why not use a simple for loop

Comment: Is the sequence always like this? If so, you could try to get the highest value and step back to the previous highest value.

Comment: Have you already tried anything and got stacked, or just posted a question to get full solution without any work?

Comment: Dean, what should the code print for `1,4,2,5,3,6` ?

Comment: @marcin, yes i achieved it with for loop but i was more interested in an example with linq as my input is an enumerable range of data, Sorry if i came off as lazy or leechy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create your own extension method on `IEnumerable<TSource>`

```
public static class MyEnumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Descending<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
        where TSource : IComparable<TSource>
    {
        using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            TSource previous;
            if (e.MoveNext())
            {
                previous = e.Current;
                while (e.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (previous.CompareTo(e.Current) > 0)
                        yield return e.Current;
                    previous = e.Current;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var input = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

var firstDescending = input.Descending().First();
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need to put a constraint on it being comparable.  It would be preferrable to use a [default Comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Not Linq but the C# way:

```
    public int FirstDecreasingIndex(IList<int> myList)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (myList[i] > myList[i + 1])
                return i+1;
        }
        return -1; //Or some other value
    }
```

For this input:
`{ 1,2,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,9 }` The function will return `3` as it's the first index where the lists begins decreasing for the first time.

Comment: Shouldn't it return 2 instead of 3?

Comment: no look at the question. the index of the first number that is lower than its predecessor is wanted

Comment: That's not clear if OP want's the value or the index

Comment: He wants to know the first item that begins decreasing. Or maybe he wants the value of that index. If so it should return `myList[i+1]`

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: look at the topic

Answer (score 3):

For a truly functional approach:

```
List<int> numbers = ...;
var firstDecreasingValue =
    numbers.Skip(1).Zip(numbers, (number, previous) => new { number, previous })
           .Where(x => x.number.CompareTo(x.previous) < 0)
           .Select(x => x.number)
           .First();
```

Answer (score 1):

not totally linq, but close enough I think

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
var index = Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count).First(i => i > 0 && list[i] < list[i - 1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

And here is a "oneliner" using `Enumerable.Aggregate` and `Tuple`:s:

```
var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1 };
var idx = numbers.Aggregate(Tuple.Create(true, 0, 0),  (tuple, x) => 
          tuple.Item1
          ? tuple.Item3 <= x 
            ? Tuple.Create(true, tuple.Item2 + 1, x) 
            : Tuple.Create(false, tuple.Item2, x)
          : tuple)
          .Item2;
```

The aggregate tuple stores three values:

1. Whether or not to continue searching for increases,
2. array index, incremented until the first decrease is detected,
3. item value to be used for comparison with subsequent value in array, updated until first decrease is detected.

When aggregation is complete, pick the `Item2` value from the tuple, where the index of the first decrease is stored.

Output from the above code would be `9` i.e. the base zero index of the first decreased value. If you instead return `Item3` from the aggregate tuple, you get the first decreased value (or the last value if the sequence is entirely non-decreasing).